# LINQ-to-entities: predicating on a DateTime field causes AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities, mysql-connector

I have the following code:

```
var dtThreshold = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

using (var db = new TermbaseEntities())
{
    var tc = (from termChanges in db.st_element_audit_log
                where termChanges.element_type_id == (long) ElementType.Term
                      && termChanges.recorded > dtThreshold
              select termChanges).ToArray();

    ...
}
```

In the DB entities, st_element_audit_log.recorded is a `DateTime` property.

It's a fairly trivial statement, but running it causes the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: AccessViolationException
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

If I comment-out the line

```
                      && termChanges.recorded > dtThreshold
```

Then that query runs without any problems, suggesting that MySQL ConnectorNET only has a problem with the DateTime predicate.

Can anyone suggest a way around this? I don't believe that it's poor coding on my side that's causing this (but I'm happy to be told if that *is* is the case), but I still need a way to retrieve those entities.